# Swift loading images from firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

Does someone know why this is not working? The tableView is empty and not showing anything even though there are items in the database and storage. This worked fine before I implemented the loading of the images from storage which you will see at the bottom of this code that I have pasted in. The `food.append()` statement used to be outside the `storageRef.getData()` closure (since it didn't exist) however if I take it out now it won't be able to access `recipeImage` since it's declared within the closure. Is it not working because it's in the closure? If so how do I fix it?

```
let parentRef = Database.database().reference().child("Recipes")
    let storage = Storage.storage()

    parentRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

        //Processes values received from server
        if ( snapshot.value is NSNull ) {

            // DATA WAS NOT FOUND
            print("– – – Data was not found – – –")

        } else {

            //Clears array so that it does not load duplicates
            food = []

            // DATA WAS FOUND
            for user_child in (snapshot.children) {

                let user_snap = user_child as! DataSnapshot
                let dict = user_snap.value as! [String: String?]

                //Defines variables for labels
                let recipeName = dict["Name"] as? String
                let recipeDescription = dict["Description"] as? String
                let downloadURL = dict["Image"] as? String

                let storageRef = storage.reference(forURL: downloadURL!)

                storageRef.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { (data, error) -> Void in

                    let recipeImage = UIImage(data: data!)

                    food.append(Element(name: recipeName!, description: recipeDescription!, image: recipeImage!))
                }
            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    })
```

Comment: If you move `self.tableView.reloadData()` after `food.append(Element(name: recipeName!, description: recipeDescription!, image: recipeImage!))` , see what is the behaviour?

Comment: IT WORKS!! Thank you so much

Comment: Great , I have added it as the answer

Comment: @3stud1ant3 hmm... just found a problem, it reloads the items randomly in the tableView, they are not in the same order if view is reloaded, do you know how to fix this?

Comment: One way can be to sort before reloading the tableview ,

Comment: @3stud1ant3 how is that done?

Comment: it depends on how is your data placed in the firebase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move

```
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

after

```
food.append(Element(name: recipeName!, description: recipeDescription!, image: recipeImage!))
```